# drawing line pushes a chain below

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-chains

I am trying to make a line that intersects a chain I already drew. However the drawing of the line pushes the chain below and they do not intersect. Can anybody help? I would like that the line intersects both arrows from node1 to node2 of both chains.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=10em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
   small punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=5em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm,
  start chain=1 going right, start chain=2 going right]
     \node[punktchain, join] (start) {Static MC};

     \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Uniform Generator};
     \node[punktchain, join] (u) {U};
     \draw (2.2,1) --(2.2,5);




    % SECOND CHAIN
    \node[punktchain, below=1cm of start] (x) {...};
    \node[punktchain,join] (y) {...};
    \node[punktchain, join] (z) {...}

    ;




\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{fig:6forces}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You can see it in picture [image]

Comment: Could you make your working example a bit more minimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
\draw[shorten <= -1cm,shorten >= -1cm] ($(start)!0.5!(probf)$) --($(x)!0.5!(y)$);
```

just before `\end{tikzpicture}`

`$(start)!0.5!(probf)$`  is the point midway between nodes `start` and `probf` and `$(x)!0.5!(y)$` is the point midway between nodes `x` and `y`. Both these need the `calc` library of `tikz` which you have already loaded. So you are drawing a line from the point midway between `start` and `probf` to the point midway between `x` and `y`. Now we extend this line on both sides by `shorten`. `shorten >=` on one side and `shorten <=` on the other side by `-1cm` (minus sign will extend the line).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=10em,
    minimum height=3em,
    text centered,
    on chain},
   small punktchain/.style={
    rectangle,
    rounded corners,
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=5em,
    minimum height=3em,
    text centered,
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=8em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=10em,
    minimum height=3.5em,
    text centered,
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm,
  start chain=1 going right, start chain=2 going right]
     \node[punktchain, join] (start) {Static MC};

     \node[punktchain, join] (probf)      {Uniform Generator};
     \node[punktchain, join] (u) {U};
    % SECOND CHAIN
    \node[punktchain, below=1cm of start] (x) {...};
    \node[punktchain,join] (y) {...};
    \node[punktchain, join] (z) {...};
    %% vertical line
    \draw[shorten <= -1cm,shorten >= -1cm] ($(start)!0.5!(probf)$) --($(x)!0.5!(y)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{fig:6forces}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Can you explain me a bit what did you do here?

Comment: @Paramar Sure, Please see the update..

Comment: Thanks. One comment: When I expand the line further than -1cm (like -3 cm) why is the label not pushed further to the bottom?

Comment: @Paramar Which label?

Comment: The "Figure 1". When the line is expanded further below, it surpasses the "Figure 1" word which is not so pleasing to the eye.

Comment: @Paramar It won't like that. Use `\draw ([yshift=3cm]$(start)!0.5!(probf)$) --([yshift=-3cm]$(x)!0.5!(y)$);` instead. Here no extending but shifting so figure will move down.